# error "None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied" with cxf wsdl2java generated webservice

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf

I'm trying to build a web service client based on a wsdl file. This client is used in a java webapp built with `Spring` and `Maven`. I have used `cxf 2.4.9` as an `eclipse` plugin to generate the `java` code from the wsdl file. The web service needs a username and a password to be used so the wsdl file contains a **usernameToken policy**.

When I test the generated service, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
```

Here are the code snippets of the web service:

The policy part of the wsdl file:

```
<wsp:UsingPolicy wssutil:Required="true" />
<wsp:Policy wssutil:Id="policy">
    <ns0:SupportingTokens
        xmlns:ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200512">
        <wsp:Policy>
            <ns0:UsernameToken
                ns0:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200512/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <ns0:WssUsernameToken11 />
                </wsp:Policy>
            </ns0:UsernameToken>
        </wsp:Policy>
    </ns0:SupportingTokens>
</wsp:Policy>
```

The generated service:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "EURLexWebService", 
              wsdlLocation = "http://eur-lex.europa.eu/EURLexWebService?wsdl",
              targetNamespace = "http://eur-lex.europa.eu/search") 
public class EURLexWebService extends Service {

public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://eur-lex.europa.eu/search", "EURLexWebService");
public final static QName EURLexWebServicePort = new QName("http://eur-lex.europa.eu/search", "EURLexWebServicePort");
static {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://eur-lex.europa.eu/EURLexWebService?wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EURLexWebService.class.getName())
            .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                 "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "http://eur-lex.europa.eu/EURLexWebService?wsdl");
    }
    WSDL_LOCATION = url;
}

public EURLexWebService(URL wsdlLocation) {
    super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE);
}

public EURLexWebService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
}

...
```

}

The code used to call the webservice:

```
URL wsdlURL = EURLexWebService.WSDL_LOCATION;
File wsdlFile = getWsdlFile();
if (wsdlFile.exists()) {
     wsdlURL = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
}

EURLexWebService ss = new EURLexWebService(wsdlURL, EURLexWebService.SERVICE);
EURLexWebServiceProvider port = ss.getEURLexWebServicePort();

Map ctx = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
ctx.put("ws-security.username", "mylogin");
ctx.put("ws-security.password", "mypassword");

doQuery(port);
```

and finally the full stackstrace:

```
org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.chooseAlternative(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:165)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.finalizeConfig(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:145)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.initialize(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:141)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.createEndpointPolicyInfo(PolicyEngineImpl.java:555)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:301)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getClientEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:283)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.PolicyUtils.getClient(PolicyUtils.java:150)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.<init>(HTTPConduit.java:309)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getConduit(HTTPTransportFactory.java:248)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(SoapTransportFactory.java:229)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(SoapTransportFactory.java:236)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.getSelectedConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:88)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.UpfrontConduitSelector.selectConduit(UpfrontConduitSelector.java:71)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.getConduit(ClientImpl.java:842)
at com.mds.impco.el.webapp.controllers.HomeController.callEurlexWebService(HomeController.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I read a few topics on this subject. In one of them there was the code snippet where I put the username and password in the request context map but it doesn't work.

I tested the web service with SoapUI and it works so it seems the problem is with my java code...

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You created a Map ctx object; but I don't see you using it anywhere in your code....

Comment: I don't need to use the map in my own code. It's just a reference to the requestContext which is probably used by cfx objects later when calls to the webservice are made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! First there was an error in the wsdl file.

The namespace `http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200512` was incorrect and had to be replaced by `http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702` or `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy`.

As there is a policy defined in the wsdl file, populating the `requestContext` map is the right thing to do.

And finally, in the `doQuery(EurlexWebServiceProvider port)` method, I build a `SearchRequest` object which is a parameter of the webservice call and I forgot to set a property of this object which was required for the request to be valid.